# Rewrite subdomain and URL-path to URL parameters but allow access to files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with my `.htaccess` file and setting it up the way I want it. The main function is a website that gets the language from the subdomain and the current page from the subfolders.

### Requirements

I have three requirements that I need my `.htaccess` file to do;

1. Wildcard subdomain redirected to **lang** variable
2. Subfolder(s) redirected to **page** variable
3. Local files respected **(this is where I'm stuck)**
4. **(Bonus)** Split up the page variable into segments for each slash; page, sub1, sub2, etc

### Examples

- `en.example.com/hello` -> `/index.php?lang=en&page=hello`
- `es.example.com/hola` -> `/index.php?lang=es&page=hola`
- **(Bonus)** `en.example.com/hello/there/sir` -> `index.php?lang=en&page=hello&sub1=there&sub2=sir`

### My current .htaccess

This is my current setup which actually *kinda* works, if I don't need any local files (lol). This means local images aren't found when my `.htaccess below` is active. I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to respect local files but that breaks the whole file it seems - and I don't know why.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((?!www).+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?lang=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ((?!www).+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?lang=%1&page=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: "but that breaks the whole file it seems" - what do you mean by this? And where exactly are you adding these _condition(s)_? Can your URLs contain dots? Does it matter if you have _empty_ URL params? eg. `page=`, rather than the URL param not being present at all? - which is what you appear to be trying to do. Your PHP should handle both scenarios, so the `.htaccess` code could be simplified.

Comment: Regarding your "Bonus" to split up the URL-path into separate URL params... why not do that in your PHP script? That would seem to be far more flexible.

Comment: @MrWhite - the whole .htaccess file stops working and I get nothing out of it; no variables at all. So it breaks. :) And yes, of course I can just explode by "/" and be done with it, I just thought it would be nice to learn.

Comment: What was the actual HTTP response? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URLs don't contain dots then exclude dots from your regex - this naturally excludes real files (that contain a dot before the file extension). This avoids the need for a filesystem check.

Your script should handle `/index.php?lang=%1` and `/index.php?lang=%1&page=` exactly the same, so the first rule is superfluous.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> ```

This rule should be first, not embedded in the middle.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /index.php?lang=%1&page=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Your last rule that rewrites everything else to `index.php`, less the `lang` URL param is questionable. Why not just include this in the preceding rule and validate the language in your script? Which you need to do anyway.

Assuming there is always a subdomain, then your rules could then be reduced to:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /index.php?lang=%1&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Requests for the `www` *language* are then validated by your script and defaulted accordingly, as if the `lang` param was not passed at all (which you need to be doing anyway).

If your subdomain is entirely optional and you are accessing the domain apex then make it optional (with a non-capturing group) in the regex:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:(.+)\.)?example\.com [NC]
:
```

The `lang` param would then be *empty* if the domain apex was requested.

> (Bonus) `en.domain.com/hello/there/sir` -> `index.php?lang=en&page=hello&sub1=there&sub2=sir`

It would be preferable (more efficient, flexible, etc) to do this in your PHP script, not `.htaccess`.

But in `.htaccess` you could do something like this (instead of the existing rule):

```
:
RewriteRule ^([^/.]*)(?:/([^/.]+))?(?:/([^/.]+))?(?:/([^/.]+))?(?:/([^/.]+))?$ /index.php?lang=%1&page=$1&sub1=$2&sub2=$3&sub3=$4&sub4=$5 [QSA,L]
```

The URL params are *empty* when that path segment is not present.

It is assumed the URL-path does not end in a slash (the above will not match if it does, so a 404 will result). If a trailing slash needs to be permitted then this should be implemented as a canonical redirect to remove the trailing slash. Or reverse the logic to enforce a trailing slash.

This particular example allows up to 4 additional "sub" path segments, eg. `hello/1/2/3/4`. You can extend this method to allow up to 8 (since there is a limit of 9 backreferences in the Apache syntax) if required. Any more and you will need to use PHP. (You could potentially handle more using `.htaccess`, but it will get very messy as you will need to employ additional *conditions* to capture subsequent path segments.)

---

> I tried adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` to respect local files but that breaks the whole file it seems

That should also be sufficient (if dots are permitted in your URLs). But I wonder where you were putting it? It should not "break" anything - it simply prevents the rule from being processed if the request does map to a file - the rule is "ignored".

This is of course assuming you are correctly linking to your resources/static assets using root-relative (starting with a slash) or absolute (starting with scheme + hostname) URLs. If you are using relative URLs then they will probably result in 404s. If this is the case then see [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/86458/1243) to the following question on the Webmasters stack:

- https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css

Comment: It works! Thank you so much :) I sincerely appreciate it!